# Architecture of super ad blocker HTTP modification

Tags: windows, http, adblock

Not totally sure which (...if any) *exchange site is the place for this question, but I'm hoping someone can describe the architecture of an OS level ad-blocker. Somehow it must be intercepting HTTP(/HTTPS?) and modifying the responses. I'd be glad to know specifically how this is achieved--is there a local HTTP proxy? is this a TCP filter using a KMDF WFP callout? Some other cool thing I've never even heard of?

Comment: This is probably too broad of a question.  All of your options are plausible.  There are plenty of other options as well such as network appliances, modifying the local DNS, browser plugins, ...

Comment: Guys at SuperUser, might be more helpful.